# Grafana add string to value in table

Tags: json, grafana, dashboard

I`m setting up a dashboard in Grafana and trying to modify a specific value in table panel, the data comes from the Infinity datasource (using a JSON get) and i have 3 inputs, that return different values but some of them are the same, and i want to rename those values in order to know from which server they come.

For example:

Server1:

| Health | Name | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HEALTH_OK | AdminServer | RUNNING |
| HEALTH_OK | service1 | RUNNING |

Server2:

| Health | Name | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HEALTH_OK | AdminServer | RUNNING |
| HEALTH_OK | service2 | RUNNING |

I want to rename the AdminServer name into  server1-AdminServer and the same for server2, or all the values in the name field to be server1-AdminServer, server1-service1, server1-service2 etc...
Tried using transform function from Grafana, parsing the json.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this in Grafana, there should be two alternatives. You can use **value mappings** or **regex-based renaming**.

**Value Mappings:**

1. Navigate to the panel you want to update in Grafana.
2. Hover over any part of the panel you want to work on to display the menu in the top right corner.
3. Click the menu and select Edit.
4. Scroll down to the Value mappings section and expand it.
5. Click Add value mappings.
6. For each value you want to rename, click Add a new mapping and specify the original value and the desired renamed value. For example:
   Original value: AdminServer
   Renamed value: server1-AdminServer
7. Repeat this process for other values as needed.
8. Save your changes.

**Regex-Based Renaming:**
If you prefer more flexibility, you can use a transform operation in Grafana to rename values based on regular expressions.

1. In your table panel, go to the Transform section.
2. Choose the Rename by regex option.
3. Configure the transformation using regular expressions to match the original values and replace them with the desired renamed values.
   4.For example, you can use a regex pattern like `^AdminServer$` to match the exact value “AdminServer” and replace it with “server1-AdminServer”.
   5.Save your changes.

I hope this helps you!!